# MongooseIM Push Notifications for MUC`s messages (not MUC light)

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, mongoose-im

I was trying to use MongooseIM with mod_muc (just mod_muc, not mod_muc_light) and found that users do not receive Push Notifications for messages that they could miss in MUC room while being offline.
I am using MongooseIM with mod_event_pusher_push_plugin_defaults and MongoosePush service. Push Notification works fine for MUC light but doesn`t work for MUC messages. Is it possible to configure MongooseIM to send Push Notifications to users for missed MUC messages?  Or how can I implement it? Please, help me

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's not possible to have push notifications for the regular MUC in MongooseIM. What do you need from MUC that you couldn't use MUC light?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I need Moderated Room when only some members are allowed to send messages to all occupants

Comment: I read information about "XEP-0045: Multi-User Chat" and there are a lot of features with roles and permissions that is necessary for me. Does mongooseim support it?

Comment: Yes, MongooseIM supports XEP-045. It only does not provide push notifications integration for the regular MUC

Comment: Four years later, is this still true?